# Find the largest element that properly divides another one in a list

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sorting

I have a list as input:

```py
Num_list = [4,16,64,2,8]
```

And I want to output:

```py
Largest_Product_Integer = 16
```

I need to output the largest integer in the list that divides another integer in the same list. In this case it should be `16` because `16` divides `64`. However including the squaring of numbers also, 8^2 = 64 , but 16 is larger than 8 hence 16 is the largest_product_integer. I want to return `-1` if no such element can be found.

Comment: Why is the answer not `16` since `16 * 4 = 64`?

Comment: corrected, thanks!

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: Why is the answer not `64` as `16*4 = 64`??

Comment: Answer is not 64 as I need to use two other elements in the list to be multiplied to give 64. Hence 16 will be the largest_product_integer

Comment: @User112211 Your question says `the largest integer which is another product of 2 other numbers` — that's 64.

Comment: `8^2` is not the product of `8` and `2`

Comment: Have reworded question to hopefully remove any ambiguity

Comment: @ChatterOne I think at this point the question's phrasing and rephrasing is so bad that writing some code for OP could be the best way to understand what they actually want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you reworded your question, I *think* you're looking for the largest number in your list that is a [proper divisor](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Proper_divisor) of another element in your input list. I suggest you use this snippet:

```py
Num_list = [4,16,64,2,8]

print(max([i for i in Num_list if any((n % i == 0 and i != n for n in Num_list)) ] + [-1]))
```

It will return `-1` if no such element can be found.

Comment: This doesn't work for the squared cases. For the list [5,25,13,103], the integer 25 is the product of 5 and 5, hence 5 here will be largest divisor